# Does the thing in constructor also called when retrieving object from database java hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to know that if I have this in my constructor:

```
public class Foo {
    private final String param1;
    private final String param2;

    foo() { this.param1 = "param1";  }     
}
```

Now i want to know that if i retrieve object from database then does same constructor gets called or it only happens at first time only

Comment: sorry i just coped the wrong code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Hibernate invokes the no-arg constructor for every entity instance it creates and populates. Your above code is not Java code, though.

Comment: But if i set some property in no arg constructor. Then will that be executed. like if old value of a=3. then will the the new value become 2

Comment: Hibernate will call the constructor, so all the code in the constructor will be executed, obviously. After the constructor is called, it will populate the created instance with the values coming from the database. So if a is a persistent field, and its value in database is 2341, the value assigned in the constructor (2) will be overwritten with 2341. Why don't you test it yourself?

Comment: thanks buddy , actually i had that doubt in mind but now its cleared. i will test now